# Javascript division on Lodash Wrapper object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I recently upgraded to [Lodash 3.10.1](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.10.1/doc/README.md) and I noticed something odd.

Say I have an array of numbers and I want to get the maximum in the array then half it:

```
var series = [ 6, 8, 2 ];

var highestTotal = _.chain(series)
                    .max();

console.log('highestTotal is ', highestTotal);

var halved = highestTotal / 2;

console.log('halved is ', halved);
```

I would have thought this would have thrown an error as `highestTotal` is a Lodash Wrapper. I.e. I would havbe thought it's necessary to do:

```
var halved = highestTotal.value() / 2;
```

For it to work. But its not! How is this happening?

Jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o7a93v8u/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s because lodash wrapper object expose a `.valueOf` method (which is aliased to `.value`) and automatically called by JavaScript when a primitive value is expected (e.g. within an arithmetic operation).

[From the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf):

```
function myNumberType(n) {
    this.number = n;
}

myNumberType.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this.number;
};

myObj = new myNumberType(4);
myObj + 3; // 7
```